Extra keyboard layout shown in xkbmap compared to settings
If I type setxkbmap -query in the terminal of my Ubuntu 22.04 system I get this output:
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     se,ru,us
variant:    ,,
options:    lv3:ralt_switch,grp_led:scroll

Comparing this to the available languages in Settings -> Keyboard, there is a mismatch.

setxkbmap -print returns
xkb_keymap {
    xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
    xkb_types     { include "complete"  };
    xkb_compat    { include "complete+ledscroll(group_lock)"    };
    xkb_symbols   { include "pc+se+ru:2+us:3+inet(evdev)+level3(ralt_switch)"   };
    xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc105)" };
};

I've had trouble since before trying to customise my primary (Swedish) keyboard layout, as this would break my keyboard settings upon restart, locking the keyboard layout to that of US English, while removing the possibility to select any other layout.
Is it working as designed that there is a third keyboard in my xkbmap query? If not: how do I get rid of it?
